# Android external libraries update

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

is there a way to update android external libraries or SDK's automatically, like updating facebook-SDK or twitter-SDK automatically and not manually downloading them and importing them to workspace ?

Comment: No. As far as I know!

Comment: on what i've researched recently, this is possible through using android maven plug-in

Comment: you updated android SDK or Facebook SDK with that?

Comment: yep, you can check this [link](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-config-build.html).